# Allowing variable length arguments to Angular's $resource?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-resource

Here's the issue, I have multiple API calls to make along the lines of:

`www.domain.com/foo/bar?token=12345`

There may be more subdirectories in-between, there may be less.

I'm currently using $resource

```
agentApp.factory('apiFactory', function($resource) {
    return $resource('www.domain.com/v1/' + ':folder', 
    {
        'query': {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true
    }
});
```

Which gets called as follows:

```
apiFactory.query({folder: 'foo', token: '12345'}, function() {...})
```

I would like to make this more extensible as I have the need to occasionally change the `isArray` value to `false`, and the amount of subdirectories in the URL are unknown on occasion, so I'd prefer to not use `$resource`'s `:token` structure, and rather just have one that takes a string.

Is there a service I could create that would allow me to make the call as follows:

```
apiService.query(urlStringAndQueries, booleanForIsArray).then(function(response) { ...do something with response });
```

So far I've attempted the following, which obviously doesn't give me what I want, I'm not sure how to get $resource to actually kick off the API call, I put this down to a fundamental misunderstanding of how $resource works:

```
agentApp.factory('apiService', ['$resource', '$q', function ($resource, $q) {
    var factory = {
        query: function (urlStringAndQueries, isArray) {
            return $q(
                function() {
                    $resource('www.domain.com/v1/' + ':location', { location: urlStringAndQueries }, {
                        'query': {
                            method: 'GET',
                            isArray: isArray
                        }
                    });
                }
            )
        },
    return factory;
}]);
```

Which I attempt to call as follows:

```
apiService.query('/foo/bar?token=12345', true)
    .then(function(response) { ...do something with response });
```

Any help and/or advice is very much appreciated.
Thanks!

**EDIT: Here's my solution until a more generic pattern comes along**

I couldn't simply provide an extra entity to the base URL string externally, e.g. `foo/bar?token=12345`, due to `$response` inherently encoding URL, so the characters (/?=) get converted into their encoded counterparts. Hence the separating of strings in the pattern:

```
agentApp.factory('apiService', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    var factory = {
        resourceObj: function(isArray, urlStringAndQueries) {

            /* urlStringAndQueries will be variadic parameters,
            so we deconstruct them for use in the URL */

            var location1, location2, location3, locations = [];

            angular.forEach(arguments, function(path) {
                locations.push(path);
            });

            return $resource(vapiURL + vapiVer + '/' + ':location1' + '/' + ':location2' + '/' + ':location3' + '/' + ':location4', {
                location1: locations[1],
                location2: locations[2],
                location3: locations[3],
                location4: locations[4],
            }, {
                'query': {
                    method: 'GET',
                    isArray: isArray
                },
                'save': {
                    method: 'POST',
                    isArray: isArray
                }
            })
        }
    };
    return factory;
}]);
```

This solution still assumes I'll have a finite amount of paths, which isn't ideal but at least it's easy to reuse.

Still open to more and better suggestions :)

Comment: You could write a service that uses `$http` directly instead of `$resource`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are returning promise object from your service method again, while $resource return promise itself. Don't do that

**Code**

```
agentApp.factory('apiService', ['$resource', '$q', function($resource, $q) {
    var factory = {
        resourceObj: function(urlStringAndQueries, isArray) {
            return $resource('www.domain.com/v1/' + ':location', {
                location: urlStringAndQueries
            }, {
                'query': {
                    method: 'GET',
                    isArray: isArray
                }
            });
        )
    }
}]);
```

Call factory method then you'll get access to resource object then call its `query` of that resource object method

**Controller**

```
apiService.resourceObj('/foo/bar?token=12345', true).query()
    .then(function(response) { ...do something with response });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @pankajparkar. There's a few issues with your code as it stands - need to return the `factory` object variable at the end of the service, and as you rightfully mentioned `$resource` returns its own promise, hence we can simply write the function inside of the query parens. I edited my answer to reflect my solution for now, with your help. Thanks again.

Comment: @KyleGillen you could vote up, if it does help you..Thanks :)